# getSelectedItem mediante un String obtenido de un Jtable

Tags: java, combobox, jtable

estoy precisando convertir un valor de una celda de una tabla para que traslade ese resultado a un JComboBox lo he logrado hacer pero con JTextField, pero a la hora de cargar el resultado en un JComboBox no puedo hacer que se cargue el valor de la tabla en el mismo.
Añado el código y una imagen gif para que vean el funcionamiento.
La idea principal es que cuando hagan click en la tabla, se carguen todos los JTextField y los JComboBox para que puedan editarlo y guardar los cambios. E intentado usar un getSelectedItem pero creo me da error ya que lo estoy implementando mal.

```
private void tablaResultadosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) tablaResultados.getModel();
    String tableId = tableModel.getValueAt(tablaResultados.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
    //LA SECCION DE ABAJO ME PERMITE SELECCIONAR RESULTADOS DE LA TABLA PARA LUEGO EDITARLOS
    int fila = this.tablaResultados.getSelectedRow();//CREO FILA PARA LA SELECCION DE LA TABLA Y ROW
    this.id.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
    this.crearCargo.getSelectedItem(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());//ESTE<<<<<<<
    this.crearNombre.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
    this.crearApellido.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
    this.crearMail.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString());
    this.crearTelefono.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString());
    this.crearUsuario.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 6).toString());
    this.crearPassword.setText(this.tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 7).toString());
    //FIN DE LA SECCION
}
```

Y a continuación le muestro lo que genera, y para que lo preciso, hago click en la tabla y se cargan todos los valores en los campos de arriba, la idea es que tambien se modifique el **JComboBox** de nombre **crearCargo**. Con el valor de la tabla que esta en la columna 2 que la llamo fila 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran iluminar se los agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo pude solucionar, convirtiendo en string el resultado que obtenia de seleccionar la Jtable de la siguiente manera

```
crearCargo.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(tablaResultados.getValueAt(fila, 1)));
```